# Timestamps in MongoDB logs - start or end of execution time?

Tags: mongodb

Typical load for this MongoDB instance is 300 commands per second and normally every command completes well under 50ms, even under load tests using all possible queries. Sometimes an issue arises where a block of commands is taking upwards of a few seconds.

The timestamps for the complete block of problematic commands in the mongod log have identical values. Other than the sample log line included below, there are 20 other commands (mix of insert and update) in the log with the exact same timestamp of 10:32:30.456, but with very different execution times recorded, ranging from 2 seconds to 6 seconds.

Is the timestamp I see in the mongod log the time when the command was started, or the time when it finished?

Sample mongod log entry:

> 2016-03-10T10:32:30.456+0000 I COMMAND  [conn94] command sampleDb.sampleEvents command: insert { ... } ninserted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:40 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 1, w: 1 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 4555ms

Comment: Logic would say "after" and therefore "finished", though it is indeed not documented anywhere so you would need to look at the code to be sure. Since there is of course an execution time, the command has to have finshed before such data could be collected and written. It also would not make sense to then use the "starting" timestamp for the operation, since if one operation was started after another but completed first then the timestamps recorded would not be in order. The typical convention for logfiles anyway is that the timestamp refers to when the logging entry was written.

Answer (score 1):

Having to deal with the same question I found a suit of tools that have been a great help in analyzing mongod log files: [mtools](https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools).
One of its tools with the name `mplotqueries` has an option `--operation-start-time` [described](https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools/wiki/mplotqueries#operation-start-time) as follows:

> Events are written to the log file when they finish, and by default, `mplotqueries` plots the operation on the x-axis at that point in time. Sometimes, it can be useful to see when operations started instead. For operations that have a duration (queries, updates, etc.) `mplotqueries` can subtract the duration and plot the operation when it started instead. Turn this feature on with the `--optime-start` flag.

This was the only hint I found on that topic.

PS: The other tool to visualize log entries called `mlogvis` doesn't have this option, but here is a code snippet that does the same thing:

```js
//This goes to adopt all datetime fields in the datastructure
if(!d.hasOwnProperty('logtime') && d[this.yaxis_field] && d.datetime){
    d.logtime = d.datetime;
    if(d.duration > 0){
        var logtime = new Date(d.datetime);
        var starttime = new Date(logtime.valueOf()- d.duration - (logtime.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000));
        d.datetime = starttime.toISOString();
        d.line_str = d.datetime + ' - ' + d.line_str;
    }
}
```

for that you need to modify the generated html file and add the snippet into the `this.data.filter` function inside `MLogVis.prototype._recalc_data_extents`.